# O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção. Nome do parâmetro: index

Tags: c#, asp.net

Olá, Sou novo por aqui, entre tanto estou tentando Listar as redes sociais e identificar através do campo descricaorede.
sei  que poderia procurar o resultado mas não estou conseguindo fazer as combinações ou escrever da forma certa o algoritmo, desde já obrigado.

Seguinte Erro "O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção. Nome do parâmetro: index"

```
        redesocialDTO.idcliente = Sessao.ID_cliente;
        redesocialDTO.idTipoUser = Sessao.ID_TipoUser;
        List<redesocialDTO> ListaRedeDTO = redesocialBLL.FiltrarRede_ID(redesocialDTO);

        if(ListaRedeDTO[1].descricaorede == "URL Linkedin")
        {
            urllinkedin.Text = ListaRedeDTO[1].linkrede;
        }
        if (ListaRedeDTO[2].descricaorede == "URL Whatsapp")
        {
            urlWhatsapp.Text = ListaRedeDTO[2].linkrede;
        }
        if (ListaRedeDTO[4].descricaorede == "URL Instagram")
        {
            urlinstagram.Text = ListaRedeDTO[3].linkrede;
        }
```

Comment: dê uma olhanda nos campos que retorna em `ListaRedeDTO`, esse erro indica que um índice (o que passa nos `[]`)  não existe...lembre-se que o índice começa a contar em zero `[0]`

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

O erro que você está recebendo quer dizer que você está tentando acessar uma posição na sua lista que não existe. Por exemplo tentando acessar a posição 5 de uma lista com 4 elementos. Lembre-se que os índices começam do 0, então para acessar a posição 1 você usa o 0, a posição 2 você usa o 1 e assim por diante.
Sua pergunta ficou um pouco vaga. Da próxima vez tente dar mais detalhes do problema.